# Como fazer para que o tamanho da fonte se ajuste automaticamente ao tamanho de uma div

Tags: html, css, html5

Olá, tenho uma div de `300px` por `300px`, nela eu deixo um texto que vem de um banco de dados, o problema é que tem vezes em que o texto dentro da div ultrapassa o tamanho da mesma, deixando invavel para impressão. Eu preciso saber se tem como redimentcionar automaticamente o tamanho da fonte para que o texto da `div` nunca ultrapasse `300px` de altura e nem de largura.
veja como o problema em 
http://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/1747/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#conteudo').textfill({
        maxFontPixels: 12
    });
});
```

```css
#conteudo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-textfill.github.io/js/textfill/jquery.textfill.js"></script>

<div id="conteudo">
    <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat at tortor sit amet euismod. Pellentesque dapibus bibendum felis, sit amet consectetur eros condimentum in. Cras efficitur tellus id lectus sagittis tincidunt. Aliquam imperdiet sem at laoreet elementum. Curabitur aliquam gravida varius. Praesent id pulvinar nulla. Mauris ultricies iaculis augue bibendum consequat.

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat at tortor sit amet euismod. Pellentesque dapibus bibendum felis, sit amet consectetur eros condimentum in. Cras efficitur tellus id lectus sagittis tincidunt. Aliquam imperdiet sem at laoreet elementum. Curabitur aliquam gravida varius. Praesent id pulvinar nulla. Mauris ultricies iaculis augue bibendum consequat.
    </span>
</div>
```

Utilizei o plugin jQuery [textfill](http://jquery-textfill.github.io/). Ele redimensiona a fonte de acordo com a div. Realizei alguns testes com o preview de impressão do Chrome e no IE 11 e manteve o tamanho da fonte.

Comment: Aqui ta tudo fora da div no seu snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esse problema das palavras ultrapassarem a `div`, você pode usar a propriedade `overflow: auto;`

No seu exemplo ficaria assim:

```
div {
    font-size: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Veja no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVB3t/1749/).

Comment: Oi Tais. Ele pede uma div fixa 300x300. O texto é que precisa diminuir automaticamente.

Comment: @Bacco, acho que não tem como fazer isso só com CSS.

Comment: De fato, até hoje só vi com JS mesmo. E nenhum muito simples não.

Comment: @Bacco, pois é, com JS tem como, mas eu não sei qual o objetivo dele. Na minha opinião, pensando na usabilidade, é melhor o usuário dar um scroll, do que a letra diminuir o tamanho.

Answer (score 2):

Também da para fazer ajustando o scaleY do conteúdo dentro do container:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container').each(function() {
    var scaleY = $(this).height() / $('.conteudo', this).height(),
      translateY = (($('.conteudo', this).height() - $(this).height()) / 2) * -1;
    $('.conteudo', this).css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'matrix(1,0,0,' + scaleY + ',0,' + translateY + ')',
      '-moz-transform': 'scaleY(1,0,0,' + scaleY + ',0,' + translateY + ')',
      '-ms-transform': 'scaleY(1,0,0,' + scaleY + ',0,' + translateY + ')',
      '-o-transform': 'scaleY(1,0,0,' + scaleY + ',0,' + translateY + ')',
      'transform': 'scaleY(1,0,0,' + scaleY + ',0,' + translateY + ')'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="conteudo">
    Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="conteudo">
    Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola
    Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe Hola Pepe
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

tenta isso aqui a função se chama "Viewport Sized Typography" ou em termos chulos texto escalonável tela visualização da tela.

```
p {font-size: 16px; font-size: 4vw;}
```

consulte mais informações e outras funções em

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

olha um exemplo

http://jsfiddle.net/8TrTU/2037/

Comment: Eu preciso de acordo com o tamanho da div, eu até achei uma forma parecida que funcionava mais ou menos usando `font-size: 2.6vmin;` mas só ajuda a fonte de acordo com a janela e não de acordo com a div

Comment: usa % em vez de um valor https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/

Comment: Colocando porcentagem até que vai, mas quando o texto e muito pequeno a fonte continua pequena não se ajusta.

Comment: agora é questão de ajuste, da uma lida nisto aqui https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Comment: postei um ex q eu fiz no fiddle

Comment: Bom cara, abri seu exemplo coloquei um texto com 100 palavras e a fonte não diminuiu de tamanho permaneceu igual e a div não manteve o tamanho inicial ela estouro de tamanho.

Comment: entendi vou ver se acho alguma solução

Answer (score 0):

Nesses casos o bom é usar em ao invés de px para o tamanho da fonte, você pode ver mais sobre isso aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp.

Também, o texto não deveria estourar o container dele, a menos que não existam espaços nesse teu texto, então no container use a propriedade word-wrap (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

Caso não resolva teu problema, poste aqui teu código para podermos ajudar mais...

Comment: Já tentei assim mudando as unidades de medidas, não funcionou :(

Comment: posta como está o teu código então, tanto o html como o css

Comment: editei coloquei um link para o jsfiddle com o meu problema

Comment: eu havia compreendido o seu problema de forma errada @joaopaulosantosalmeida, a princípio não sei se existe uma solução para fazer isso de forma efetiva, mas vou dar uma olhada...